# Implementing ConvertAll as an extension method

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I am trying to write an extension method for the List class for ConvertAll method (at least a method that has the same signature) and I have this

```
public static class ListExtensionsClass
    {
        public static List<TOutput> ConvertAll<TOutput>(this List<T> listInstance, Converter<T, TOutput> converter)
        {
           return null;
        }
    }
```

but I get `error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

What am I missing?

EDIT: The .NET version I am using doesn't have this method, and I need/want to write it as an extension so that I don't have to modify some existing code which already uses that method.

Comment: It will be impossible to call this method.  Anytime you try you'll just call list's instance method.

Comment: What will your method do, that `Select` from LINQ cannot do?

Answer (score 5):

You haven't defined `T` as a type parameter. Add it.

```
public static List<TOutput> ConvertAll<T, TOutput>(this List<T> listInstance, 
                                                   Converter<T, TOutput> converter)
```

Comment: When I said same signature I actually meant exactly like the original ConvertAll. In your example, when you need to call your function, you would need to add an extra type parameter between <>

Comment: @Sil Well, you can't because an extension method that has the same name and call-site parameters as an instance method will never be chosen in preference to the instance method. If I rename the extension method to `ConvertAlll`, I can happily do the following: `new[]{1,2,34,4}.ToList().ConvertAlll(a=>(double)a);`, so I'm not really sure what you are trying to tell me.

Comment: I have some code which uses the ConvertAll method and I don't want to modify it... I just want to add the ConvertAll method as an extension to the List class because the List in the version of .NET I'm using doesn't have the ConvertAll method.

Comment: @Sil When calling the extension method the argument specification will be probably redundant. So no need to modify your existing code(unless you have specified `TOutput` explicitly in your existing code.).